# No input file specified on vagrant vm

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

First off: I'm new to using Laravel. I got the homestead VM up and running with Vagrant. I checked my Homestead.yaml file and it checks out, did the additions to the hosts file as well, and created my blog according to the video tutorials on the VM.

When I run the command "php artisan serve" and try the address it returns, I get an error saying "No input file specified".

Anyone have a fix for this?

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/JeromePapalie/LaravelCode 
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel

sites: 
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: `php artisan serve` has nothing to do with Homestead or Vagrant. The command creates a local development webserver. When running the `serve` command you're trying to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or something right?

Comment: @Dees040 yeap. I'm following the tutorial videos. When I go to that address I don't see anything but "no input file..."

Comment: Try `vagrant up --provision` or `homestead up --provision` and if it's already up, just `vagrant provision` !!

Comment: @Maraboc I've tried that too. And there's still nothing. Have you come across this before?

Comment: For me no, i want just help you and i google it :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the folder structure.

[image]

This is my folder structure.

Here my `Homestead.yaml` file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: /Users/kelvin/.ssh/kevin.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/kevin

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Work/kevindev/Code
    to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Hope, you already generated ssh key file in your target folder something like this.

[image]

And then, open your host `vim /etc/hosts` and add your `homestead.app` host

[image]

Finally, go to your Homestead folder and type `vagrant up` command.

That's is.